# Navigation bar disappear when click on notification when app is in background state

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to navigate to a notification controller when user click on notification.Therefore I need to redirect them from AppDelegate class

Here is the code:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

              if  let cu = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
              {

            print(cu)
                    let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController()

                    self.window?.rootViewController = nav

                    let str = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let rr = str.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationListViewController")

                    nav.setViewControllers([cu,rr], animated: true)

                }
        }



        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

The above method is working means navigating to notification page for the first time only When I try with second time It going to dash board page.

The if condition is failing second time(getting nil value).

Help me if Some one knows

Answer (score 0):

You assign UINavigationController to rootViewController the first time you receive notification:
`let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController()
self.window?.rootViewController = nav`
Therefore, when you receive second notification, yout rootViewController is no longer UITabbarController, but rather instance of UINavigationController, so casting 
`let cu = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController` will fail.

You shouldn't create new UINavigationController. Instead, you should push your view controller

```
if let cu = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
   let str = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let rr = str.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationListViewController")
   cu.pushViewController(rr, animated: true)
}
```

or go to proper tab of you UITabBarController:

```
if let cu = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    let notificationsTabIndex = 1 //use proper tab number    
    cu.selectedIndex = notificationsTabIndex
}
```